# How to change the shape of a UISegementedControl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

So I am building a custom control for my app and it is based on a UISegmentedControl. The control itself works fine but I was wondering, how can I make the rounded corners of the UISegmentedControl less rounded?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the underlying layer and do something like this:

```
[mySegmentendControler.layer setCornerRadius:newValue];
```

Comment: I tried that but Xcode says the property corerRadius was not found?

Comment: @cgossain just do #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>, and you will see the property. Remember you have to add the framework to the project first, if you haven't already. Hope that helps.

Comment: ok now i see the property but I'm setting the corner radius to zero and nothing is changing?

Comment: Modifying the layer will change how the segmented control's drawing is composited onto the screen. It won't change the actual drawing that's done, and which comes from images. You'll have to create your own subclass of the control to do this sort of custom drawing.

Comment: Could you post some code of how I would modify the drawRect method to do draw the UISegmentedControl?